# Magento Configurable options block is missing

Tags: php, magento

I've been editing within catalog/view/options/type/configurable.phtml and this other guy working on the template has been editing all over the place. Suddenly, the whole configurable options block (that renders configurable.phtml) went missing from the page. The following blocks are still in view.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

and

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

What else might be missing that would cause the disappearance of the configurable options block? There are no errors in the server or Magento logs that are applicable. Nor any JavaScript errors. I have replaced catalog.xml, view.phtml, and configurable.phtml with fresh copies. Magento is not caching and I am refreshing the page with cntrl+shift+r to prevent browser caching. I have taken the above code out of the if statements... Still no options block!

Comment: And if you view page source of the code on the product detail page, it shows the code I have in configurable.phtml as commented out!

Comment: Try restoring the default Magento template and working from there.  It has to be caused by a modification either you or the other person made.

Comment: All default app/design/frontend/base/default files recovered... template used is renamed so it runs off default files. STILL NO CONFIG OPTIONS BOX! I'm going to try fresh core files too... As for the product itself, it is configurable, has the associated products, in "in stock" "available" and has 1000 quantity for each simple. Any other issues with product it could be?

Comment: is this happening on one product, or all configurable products?

Comment: I created a test product and then REINDEXED and it works again... how does this have anything to do with database?

Comment: Magento's database schema is pretty complex.  It could of been a variety of things.  Saving the products usually fixes the corruption in the tables (missing data required for Magento to determine if the product is configurable or not).  Glad you figured it out.

Comment: The corruption could of occurred during an import.  I'm not sure if you're importing products or not, but make sure that you have all of the essential and required data Magento needs to create and update the items.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe I troubleshooted for six hours to find that I needed to reindex...